# Docker with Gunicorn: Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, gunicorn, wsgi

I am trying to speed up `Django` by using `Gunicorn`

I have a `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx netcat postgresql-client

COPY requirements.txt /opt/

RUN pip install -r /opt/requirements.txt

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

RUN chmod +x /opt/my_turbo_app/deploy/docker/run-scripts/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/my_turbo_app/deploy/docker/run-scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
```

An `entrypoint.sh` like:

```
exec nginx &

gunicorn wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 240 --workers 7 --log-file=- --log-level debug
```

And a `requirements.txt` that has:

```
gevent==20.5.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
django==2.2.6
djangorestframework==3.10.3
```

I build the `Dockerfile` without any errors:

```
$ docker build -t my-turbo-app:latest
```

and then I run it with:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 -d --name redis redis
$ docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 -d -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust --name postgres postgres
$ docker exec -it postgres psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -c 'CREATE DATABASE turbo_db;'
$ docker run -d --name my-turbo-app --link postgres:localhost --link redis:localhost -p 8000:8000 my-turbo-app:latest
```

The container `my-turbo-app` spins up for a second, then the crashes.

Running `docker logs my-turbo-app` shows:

```
+ gunicorn wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 240 --workers 7 -k gevent --log-file=- --log-level debug
+ exec nginx
[2020-05-08 04:17:54 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: None
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:8000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 7
  worker_class: gevent
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 240
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /opt/my_turbo_app
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 0
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags: 
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: wsgi:application
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7fc906cecae8>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7fc906cecbf8>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7fc906cecd08>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7fc906cece18>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7fc906cecf28>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7fc906d050d0>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7fc906d051e0>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7fc906d052f0>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7fc906d05400>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7fc906d05510>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7fc906d05598>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7fc906d056a8>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7fc906d057b8>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7fc906d058c8>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7fc906d059d8>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2020-05-08 04:17:54 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-08 04:17:54 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-05-08 04:17:54 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[2020-05-08 04:17:54 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-05-08 04:17:55 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-05-08 04:17:55 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[2020-05-08 04:17:55 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-05-08 04:17:56 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-05-08 04:17:56 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[2020-05-08 04:17:56 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-05-08 04:17:57 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-05-08 04:17:57 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[2020-05-08 04:17:57 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-05-08 04:17:58 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-05-08 04:17:58 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: [Errno 98] Address already in use
[2020-05-08 04:17:58 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-05-08 04:17:59 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

I've tried to bind different ports, but that doesn't seem to work. How can get gunincorn to run with docker?

Comment: Are both the nginx and gunicorn processes set to listen to port 8000?  You should probably run the nginx proxy in a separate container.